# Storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier returns empty view controllers?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard

I want to lazily add a custom `UIViewController` as a child into an also custom other `UIViewController`. I try to create it in my `viewDidAppear:animated:` like this:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
  if (hostingUI == nil) { // `hostingUI` is an ivar
    hostingUI =
      [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard"
                                 bundle:[NSBundle mainBundle]]
        instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"hosting-ui"];
    [self addChildViewController:hostingUI];
  }
}
```

My ivar `hostingUI` above seems normal at first, but then I notice that all its members are `nil` (breaking into LLDB after the call to `addChildViewController`).

[image]

Obviously nothing shows up in the parent controller, and I'm missing something about how `instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier` works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`[myStoryboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"Some name"]` will let you instantiate a specific page from a storyBoard with everything covered (in/outcoming `segue`, `IBOutlets`, `IBActions`). However if this specific view is supposed to be embedded in a `NavigationController` you'll have to instantiate this one, with its `rootViewController`.